# 「書いている」vs.「書いてある」vs. 「書かれている」vs. 「書かれてある」

Tags: grammar

①　啓典には「全ての生き物は遅かれ早かれ死に至る。」と**書いてある**。

②　啓典には「全ての生き物は遅かれ早かれ死に至る。」と**書いている**。

③　啓典には「全ての生き物は遅かれ早かれ死に至る。」と**書かれている**。

④　啓典には「全ての生き物は遅かれ早かれ死に至る。」と**書かれてある**。

What is the difference between these four and which one is the most neutral one? I asked this question to a few Japanese people and received mixed answers. Most of them seemed to be in favor of the first one, but someone said that in this particular sentence, ④ is the most appropriate one since the meaning of sentence has a strong vibe; and another person corrected me to use the third option. It's pretty confusing so I'd like to learn the difference between them.